# Turn off suggestions to upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade, notification-area

How do I get my Windows 7 system tray to stop showing the Windows 10 upgrade symbol after every restart?  Here's what it looks like:

[image]

At every restart, I have to manually go in and set it to "Hide."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall Windows Update KB3035583 and restart your computer.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **how** to uninstall the update.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my own answer as I got this from Security Now transcript available on grc.com. Their answer is:

> So that's the path in the registry, HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\GWX.  Under this GWX key you create a DWORD value named Disable, with capital D, lowercase "isable," so Disable, all caps GWX, and give that the value of one, and you are done.  You have disabled Get Windows 10.  And whatever Microsoft chooses to do, apparently they will honor that.  It works today.  We can hope it continues working.

Source: https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-518.txt

Hope this helps.